# Error: "package sun.rmi.registry is declared in module java.rmi, which does not export it to the unnamed module" in gradle kotlin dsl

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, java-platform-module-system

I've a simple java 11 project build using gradle kotlin dsl. Below is build file definition -

```
plugins {
    java
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.32")
    testImplementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32")
}

configure<JavaPluginExtension> {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    val compilerArgs = options.compilerArgs
    compilerArgs.addAll(listOf("--add-exports", "java.rmi/sun.rmi.server=ALL-UNNAMED",  "--add-exports", "jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent=ALL-UNNAMED"))
}
```

There is a class in the program which uses `sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl` from restricted java.rmi module.

```
package org.example.management;

import sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl;

class JMXServer {

 // 
}
```

When compiling the code I get below error.

> /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/misc/gradle-rmi-issue/src/main/java/org/example/management/JMXServer.java:18: error: package sun.rmi.registry is not visible
> import sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl;
> ^
> (package sun.rmi.registry is declared in module java.rmi, which does not export it to the unnamed module)

I added below snippet into the build file still I get error.

```
tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    val compilerArgs = options.compilerArgs
    compilerArgs.addAll(listOf("--add-exports", "java.rmi/sun.rmi.server=ALL-UNNAMED",  "--add-exports", "jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent=ALL-UNNAMED"))
}
```

How can I make the code compile by using the code from java.rmi module.

Note: the project code in github [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/gradle-rmi-issue)

Comment: there seem to be no option for importing sun.rmi.registry module; either stay off jpms or change the registryimpl used.

Comment: if you look at my repository linked above I haven't used the jpms at all.

Comment: Have you got any resolution to this.?

Comment: @Nition Bisht yeap. I posted the solution to the issue

Answer (score 0):

Changing java.rmi/sun.rmi.server=ALL-UNNAMED to java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry=ALL-UNNAMED  fixed the issue.